# Server 2017 FTP - Stuck at Retrieving Directory Listing

Tags: iis, ftp

I've read a load of the posts on this topic, but think I'm getting my config mixed up, would appreciate if someone can help. IIS FTP works ok locally but remotely it's stuck on the directory listing, which indicates some issue with the passive ports.  My setup is this:

Windows server 2017 which is sitting behind a NAT which I have no control of.  They have opened an external address 111.222.333.444 port 1111 which they have said is setup for FTP, and it is forwarded to my local IP address 999.999.999.999.  They use port 1111 as 21 is already in use for them.

In IIS I've set my bindings to be the 999.999.999.999 address using port 1111.  At the server node I've specified 0-0 for the data channel range, and specified 111.222.333.444 as the external server (but can't specify a port).  My questions are:-

1 - Do I have the above config right?

2 - Do I need more ports opened on the external IP{ to allow for passive outbound traffic?

I've disabled Windows firewall locally to rule that out for now.

Any help / guidelines really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure additional ports to use for the data channel in IIS FTP Firewall Support, and use passive mode on the client.

[image: IIS FTP Firewall Support]

More information on active vs passive here:

http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, much appreciated.  I understand the FTP firewall support setting, but do I need to get these ports opened on the NAT for outbound traffic too?